# Extend UIScrollView insets behind keyboard on iOS11

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, ios11

Since Apple introduced `safe area insets` and `adjusted content insets` the already working UI layouting code becomes broken. In my case UIScrollView bottom inset extends when the keyboard appears:

```
func keyboardWillResize(_ notification: Notification) {
    let info: [AnyHashable: Any] = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardTop = self.view.frameOnScreen.maxY - (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.y
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.tableView.contentInset.bottom = keyboardTop
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = self.tableView.contentInset
    })
}
```

Within iOS 11 this code produces extra inset when keyboard appears, equal to tab bar height. It's obvious because now `contentInset` represents only user-defined insets, and real insets are represented by `adjustedContentInset` introduced in iOS 11.

So my question is how to deal with this case in good manner? There is option to write

```
self.tableView.contentInset.bottom = keyboardTop - self.tableView.adjustedContentInset.bottom
```

but it looks so ugly. Maybe there is built-in method to extend insets behind the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the answer is in official documentation. Instead of manually adjust content insets, we should delegate this stuff to view controller and deal with it's **safe area insets**. So, here is working code:

```
func keyboardWillResize(_ notification: Notification) {
    let info: [AnyHashable: Any] = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardTop = self.view.frameOnScreen.maxY - (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.y
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.additionalSafeAreaInsets.bottom = max(keyboardTop - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom, 0)
    })
}
```